# grunt-cli installation issue

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-cli

I installed grunt-cli both locally and globally and I can see the same in both local and global paths.

To test if the installation works, when I tried to run

```
grunt -h
```

it shows following

```
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-cli" not found. Is it installed?

    Grunt: The JavaScript Task Runner (v0.4.5)

    Usage
     grunt [options] [task [task ...]]

    Options
     --help, -h  Display this help text.
     --base  Specify .......
```

When I run grunt -v, following is part of its output

```
Registering "grunt-cli" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /Users/cominventor/myproject/node_modules/grunt-cli/package.json...OK
Parsing /Users/cominventor/myproject/node_modules/grunt-cli/package.json...OK
>> Local Npm module "grunt-cli" not found. Is it installed?
```

To install locally, I ran the following command (suggested by @Aruna)

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
npm install grunt-cli --save-dev
```

and got the following output for the second command

```
npm ERR! Darwin 16.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-cli" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v6.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.7
npm ERR! code ENOSELF

npm ERR! Refusing to install grunt-cli as a dependency of itself
npm ERR!
```

Any clues what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

How did you install the grunt?

Have you tried both global and local modules as below,

**Global**

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

**Local**

```
npm install grunt --save-dev
npm install grunt-cli --save-dev
```

Comment: I followed the steps you shared for local installation but it gave error. added the error log in my post itself as formatting is not good in comment section

Comment: Can you just try npm install grunt --save-dev ?

Comment: I tried it without sudo as you suggested and it ran without any errors/warnings but I still continue to get >> Local Npm module "grunt-cli" not found. Is it installed? whenever I run grunt -h or an application that requires grunt-cli

Comment: I am wondering why does it even show this error as grunt-cli is supposed to be installed globally

Comment: can you install the global one with sudo, `sudo npm install -g grunt-cli`

Comment: I was wondering do you have package.json file created in the same location? If not, please create a one first using `npm init`

Comment: yes i already have package.json created after running npm init.

Comment: As per my understanding, a combination of globally installed grunt-cli and locally installed grunt should work. Unable to uninstall grunt using sudo npm uninstall -g grunt

Comment: grunt -V shows
grunt-cli v1.2.0
grunt v0.4.5. can it be an issue with Gruntfile.js?

Comment: Can you try uninstalling grunt-cli and reinstalling as `npm uninstall -g grunt-cli`